# why to use daemon threads if we can use normal threads instead. what is the thing that a daemon thread can do but normal thread can’t

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

why to use daemon threads if we can use normal threads instead. what is the thing that a daemon thread can do but normal thread can’t. because up to I know, there is not much difference in those two

Comment: Answers on the "duplicate" emphasize _what_ more than _why_. The _why_ is just convenience. If your program has a thread that does not need to be cleanly shut down when the program ends, then making the thread a daemon saves you from having to write the code to shut it down.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-daemon-thread

Answer (score 0):

The Java VM will exit when the last non-daemon thread has finished. That is, a non-daemon thread will prevent the VM from exiting as long as it is running, whereas a daemon thread will not.

You would use a daemon thread for operations which make sense only as long as any non-daemon thread is running. One such example (used internally by the VM) is garbage collection.

A caveat with daemon threads is that the VM kills them off the hard way and does not even guarantee execution of `finally` blocks. That makes daemon threads dangerous to use for any operations that have effects outside the process itself.